# CSS Blur container over text

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm creating a simple website that has a fixed transparent header that goes over the content. When it is over the content, I want to make the content under it blurred so it's easier to read the menu items, logo..

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 12;
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}

.container {
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
   <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  </p>
</div>
```

I tried to add `filter: blur(3px)` to the header - no luck 
I tried to add `backdrop-filter` - also without luck

Does anyone have an idea? It can also be a JS solution.

Comment: background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

Comment: You tried backdrop-filter: blur(5px) in header? Are you using firefox?

Comment: It would be really difficult to implement blur effects for firefox. I would advise you to use `backdrop-filter: blur(3px)` for the browsers that support it and for those which don't you can use a less transparent background like `background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter: blur()` will blur the menu header itself.
`backdrop-filter` should give you the desired effect when the `background-color` is slightly transparent. however it is not supported by Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Side note for Firefox: Can be enabled by setting the `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` and `gfx.webrender.all` preference to `true` in about:config --> [Can I use: backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter)